# Generate a 10-digit alphanumeric string in NSIS

Tags: random, installation, nsis

I'd like to generate a random 10-digit alphanumeric string in an NSIS script to subsequently write to a file.

I found [this plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Rnd) which generates random numbers but I'm not sure if there's a way to turn those numbers into characters later.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StrCpy $2 ""
badrange:
    System::Call 'advapi32::SystemFunction036(*i0r0,i1)'
    IntCmpU $0 127 "" ""  badrange ; Limit to ASCII, IsCharAlphaNumeric is locale specific
    System::Call 'user32::IsCharAlphaNumericA(ir0)i.r1'
    StrCmp $1 0 badrange
    IntFmt $0 "%c" $0
    StrCpy $2 "$2$0"
    StrLen $0 $2
    IntCmpU $0 10 "" badrange
DetailPrint $2
```

Comment: Can you please explain what `*i0r0` mean? (Looking at [docs](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/System/System.html), I expect `*i0` to be the type and `r0` to be the value, but I can't figure out what type `*i0` is from it.)

Comment: @John `*i` is the type, (`INT32*` in C/C++), `0` is the input and `r0` is the output. You normally see this as `*i.r0` but I'm explicitly setting the input value as 0 here. You could also space it out to make it clearer: `*i 0 r0`

Comment: Ah, thanks. That actually made a lot more things clear.